# Stacking HTML unordered lists in Opera

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with the two unordered lists on [this web page](http://mybbwebhost.com) under the heading "Beautifully Hosted". The code for the two lists that form the image list is:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_staff.png" alt=""></div>Knowledgeable Support</li>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_backups.png" alt=""></div>Remote Backups</li>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_infinity.png" alt=""></div>Hundreds of Features</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_security.png" alt=""></div>Secure Servers and Datacenter</li>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_gears.png" alt=""></div>Web Software Auto Installer</li>
    <li><div class="image"><img src="images/icon_price.png" alt=""></div>Competitive Pricing</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#box2 ul {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#box2 li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now, this works perfectly in every browser except for Opera. In Opera, the two lists are next to each other as if it is one list and do not stack, causing the box to be too big and throwing off the whole design.

Comment: Can we see an example please, I am not quite getting what you are trying to explain. Your images are not shut, so that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Hi, you can see the code in action directly on the page that I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a width of 265px to you #box2 it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float both ULs too:

```
#box2 ul {
    float:left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not have any effect.

Comment: Ok, two things; the code in your example is not the same as the code in the linked page. Secondly, I can't reproduce your problem. In Opera 12 on Mac and PC and Opera 10(on Mac) the problems you describe are not visible.